# Amazon VPC to VPC connection

Tags: amazon-web-services, ipsec, amazon-vpc

I have created an Amazon EC2 Linux instance running Racoon and this one is trying to connect other Amazon VPC IPSec interface. I use my Elastic IP address as a customer gateway but I'm getting these failures.

Does anyone have an idea regarding this?

```
2013-04-04 12:43:29: DEBUG: db :0x7f2583cda3b0: 169.254.255.93/30[0] 169.254.255.94/30[0] proto=any dir=fwd
2013-04-04 12:43:29: DEBUG: sub:0x7fff9bd61ba0: 169.254.255.93/30[0] 169.254.255.94/30[0] proto=any dir=in
2013-04-04 12:43:29: DEBUG: db :0x7f2583cda630: 169.254.255.93/30[0] 169.254.255.94/30[0] proto=any dir=in

2013-04-04 12:43:29: DEBUG: suitable inbound SP found: 169.254.255.93/30[0] 169.254.255.94/30[0] proto=any dir=in.


2013-04-04 12:43:29: DEBUG: new acquire 169.254.255.94/30[0] 169.254.255.93/30[0] proto=any dir=out

2013-04-04 12:43:29: [72.21.209.192] DEBUG: configuration "72.21.209.192[500]" selected.

2013-04-04 12:43:29: DEBUG: getsainfo params: loc='169.254.255.94/30' rmt='169.254.255.93/30' 
peer='NULL' client='NULL' id=0

2013-04-04 12:43:29: DEBUG: evaluating sainfo: loc='169.254.255.90/30', rmt='169.254.255.89/30', 
peer='ANY', id=0

2013-04-04 12:43:29: DEBUG: check and compare ids : value mismatch (IPv4_subnet)

2013-04-04 12:43:29: DEBUG: cmpid target: '169.254.255.94/30'

2013-04-04 12:43:29: DEBUG: cmpid source: '169.254.255.90/30'

2013-04-04 12:43:29: DEBUG: evaluating sainfo: loc='169.254.255.94/30', rmt='169.254.255.93/30', 
peer='ANY', id=0

2013-04-04 12:43:29: DEBUG: check and compare ids : values matched (IPv4_subnet)

2013-04-04 12:43:29: DEBUG: cmpid target: '169.254.255.94/30'

2013-04-04 12:43:29: DEBUG: cmpid source: '169.254.255.94/30'

2013-04-04 12:43:29: DEBUG: check and compare ids : values matched (IPv4_subnet)

2013-04-04 12:43:29: DEBUG: cmpid target: '169.254.255.93/30'

2013-04-04 12:43:29: DEBUG: cmpid source: '169.254.255.93/30'

2013-04-04 12:43:29: DEBUG: selected sainfo: loc='169.254.255.94/30', rmt='169.254.255.93/30', 
peer='ANY', id=0

2013-04-04 12:43:29: DEBUG:  (proto_id=ESP spisize=4 spi=00000000 spi_p=00000000 encmode=Tunnel 
reqid=0:0)

2013-04-04 12:43:29: DEBUG:   (trns_id=AES encklen=128 authtype=hmac-sha)

2013-04-04 12:43:29: DEBUG: in post_acquire

2013-04-04 12:43:29: [72.21.209.192] DEBUG: configuration "72.21.209.192[500]" selected.

2013-04-04 12:43:29: INFO: IPsec-SA request for 72.21.209.192 queued due to no phase1 found.

2013-04-04 12:43:29: DEBUG: ===

2013-04-04 12:43:29: INFO: initiate new phase 1 negotiation: 54.236.196.228[500]<=>72.21.209.192[500]

2013-04-04 12:43:29: INFO: begin Identity Protection mode.

2013-04-04 12:43:29: DEBUG: new cookie:
6d61a8ce6f870d1d

2013-04-04 12:43:29: DEBUG: add payload of len 52, next type 13

2013-04-04 12:43:29: DEBUG: add payload of len 16, next type 0

2013-04-04 12:43:29: ERROR: phase1 negotiation failed due to send error. 
6d61a8ce6f870d1d:0000000000000000

2013-04-04 12:43:29: ERROR: failed to begin ipsec sa negotication.
```

Answer (score 2):

If your two VPCs are in the same AWS region, then you can use the newly-released VPC Peering Connection feature.  It allows you to create a connection between two VPCs and route traffic through it.  See the AWS docs: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpc-peering.html

If your VPCs are in different regions, then see Amir's answer.